# Service Lifetimes in Blazor and Navigation

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

Asumme this setup:

```
Page1: 

 - Component A
 - Component B

Page2: 

 - Component C
 - Component D

Service: MyService
```

I want Component A und B to get the same instance of MyService.

Component C and D should get a fresh (and the same) instance of MyService.

When I register MyService as `transient` each Component gets a fresh instance.

When I register as `singleton`/`scoped` all components share the same instance.

Components are part of library and thus I am looking for solution that requries no or very little effort on the consuming side.

How can it be done?

Comment: Create and inject a singleton factory service. Get factory and ask for desired instance.

Comment: singleton factory might work but I want to dispose the service once the users navigated away from page 1, so I would have to do housekeeping inside the factory, sounds cumbersome

Comment: You can call to service's dispose on page1's dispose.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no built-in way to handle it. So I went with the singleton factory and linked it to the NavigationManager.

```
 public class MyServiceFactory
    {
        private NavigationManager _navigationManager;

        private Dictionary<string, MyService> _state = new Dictionary<string, MyService>();

        public MyServiceFactory(NavigationManager navigationManager)
        {
            _navigationManager = navigationManager;

            _navigationManager.LocationChanged += (s, e) =>{

                _state.Remove(_state.Keys.Single(x => x != e.Location));
            };
        }

        public MyService Get() 
        {
            if(!_state.ContainsKey(_navigationManager.Uri))
            {
                _state.Add(_navigationManager.Uri, new MyService());
            }

            return _state[_navigationManager.Uri];
        }

    }
}
```