# Common property for all Blazor pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I will need to have some properties for every page. For example,

```
private MyClass _myclass;
protected MyClass MyClass => _myclass ??= InitMyClass();
```

Instead of putting the lines on every razor page. What's the idiomatic way to do it for Blazor? A base class (how?) or do some tricks in `_Host.cshtml`?

Answer (score 3):

> A base class (how?)

Create a base class:

```
public class MyBase : ComponentBase 
{
    private MyClass _myclass;
    protected virtual MyClass MyClass => _myclass ?? ... ;
}
```

And then use the `@inherits` directive to extends the base class :

```
@page "/counter"
@inherits MyBase

<h1>Counter</h1>
...
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems the dependency injection way (in another answer) is easier. No need to create another class.

Comment: @ca9163d9 The dependency injection requires you use a single instance or  transient instances. If that's the case, you can choose the DI. But if you would like to  have a standlone property for every page itself, I believe the `@inherits` directive is preferred.

Comment: Curious, what's the problem when using `AddScope<MyClass>()`?

Comment: @ca9163d9 See [Add services to an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-services-to-an-app) : "Blazor WebAssembly apps don't currently have a concept of DI scopes."

Comment: @ca9163d9 See also [Utility base component classes to manage a DI scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) : "Services injected into the component using `@inject` or the InjectAttribute aren't created in the component's scope and are tied to the request scope."

Comment: What's the benefit of "tied to the request scope" over "created in the component's scope"?

Comment: @ca9163d9 not a benefit , but should be careful about the instances.  Think about a websocket connection where the Blazor App resides in  (Clients sends a request to blazor hub, and then upgrade the connection to websocket). When navigateing to some page, there will be a page component (`PageComponent1`) created. When you navigate to another page, then another page component(`PageComponent2`) is created. And  if you navigate back to the page 1 again, a brand new `PageComponent1` , which is not the previous `PageComponent1` instance, is created again.

Comment: @ca9163d9 (too long to paste within a single comment) However, when the two `PageComponent1` instances depend on the `MyClass` service , we should care about whether we need a brand new service every time  or share the same service.  When created by `[inject]` attribute, the are created in request scope, that means if you navigates within a single connection (without reconnect), the two `PageComponent1` shares the same instance. If you create a scope using `using(var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope()){...}` within a component, or inheritance, you'll get different service instances

Comment: If you use DI and want different services upon Navigation you might find this useful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58363327/service-lifetimes-in-blazor-and-navigation

Answer (score 2):

Add `MyClass` as scoped service and inject it wherever you want to use.

**Startup.cs**

```
service.AddScoped<MyClass>()
```

Now you can inject same instance in every page using `@inject` directive.

**Index.razor**

```
@inject MyClass myClass
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/dependency-injection

Comment: I'm converting the code from a Asp.Net web api project. The original code is implemented by creating a baseController and let every controller inherits it. Is it the same as `AddScope<...>()`?